# Epicor 10.1 implementation in .net

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I have requirement to create dashboards like `weekly sales order, monthly sales order` and these dashboard should be sent to the client everyday as an email alert.

I am new to the Epicor development, I have installed the Epicor and am able to access all the dll's.

I need to create an window service or console application in .Net using C#. Please someone guide me to achieve this and am able to create a Session to the Epicor using dlls, not getting further steps.

```
Session session = new Session(strUser, strPass, strServer,    Session.LicenseType.Default, @"C:\Epicor\ERP10.1Express\Client\config\SaaS101.sysconfig");
```

Using this Session how to call the Epicor dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the BPM which has the email template instead of using a third part app. You can first call the BAQ used in the dashboard through your BPM code and then map the result into a HTML table in the mail template. This will let you send the results through mail everyday on a scheduled basis.